# setOnChildClickListener not invoked in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have challenges to access my childItems in ExpandableListView.

I am able to access my child items when I have one single view(TextView) in the list, but when I add another view(CheckBox), then in my MainActivity, **setOnChildClickListener not invoked**.

Can someone please help me where I am doing wrong?

filter_layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

filter_group.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/laptop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

filter_list_item.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/laptop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is my FilterAdapter:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Activity context;
    private Map<String, List<String>> laptopCollections;
    private List<String> laptops;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> laptops,
                                 Map<String, List<String>> laptopCollections) {
        this.context = context;
        this.laptopCollections = laptopCollections;
        this.laptops = laptops;
    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }


    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String laptop = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_list_item, null);
        }

        TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.laptop);

        /*CheckBox delete = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setMessage("Do you want to remove?");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                List<String> child =
                                        laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition));
                                child.remove(childPosition);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });*/

        item.setText(laptop);
        return convertView;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return laptops.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return laptops.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String laptopName = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_list_group,
                    null);
        }
        TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.laptop);
        item.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        item.setText(laptopName);
        return convertView;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Following is my mainactivity. Below you can observe  **expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener()** is not getting invoked at all. Can someone help me please where I am going wrong?

```
public class FilterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.filter_layout);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
               Log.d("FilterActivity","Hello world");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Status");
        listDataHeader.add("Hospital");
        listDataHeader.add("Treatment Type");

        // Adding child data
        //Adding Status
        List<String> status = new ArrayList<String>();
        DBHelper dbHelper=new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        Cursor statusCursor=dbHelper.getTreatmentStatusTypes();
        while(statusCursor.moveToNext())
            status.add(statusCursor.getString(0));

        List<String> hospital = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor hospitalCursor=dbHelper.getListOfHospitNames();
        while(hospitalCursor.moveToNext())
            hospital.add(hospitalCursor.getString(0));



        List<String> treatmentTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor treatmentTypeCursor=dbHelper.getTreatmentTypes();
        while(treatmentTypeCursor.moveToNext())
            treatmentTypes.add(treatmentTypeCursor.getString(0));
        dbHelper.close();

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), status); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), hospital);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), treatmentTypes);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21281326/3395198

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya, i already tried return true in isChildSelectable() and i dont have clickable and focusiable parameters  in my Layout. Can you tell me anything else which i missed out?

Comment: Can someone please help me on my above problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return true in all override function which you want to implement.

```
// Listview Group click listener
expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
});
```

also return true in this function.

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
           Log.d("FilterActivity","Hello world");
            return true;
        }
});
```

Comment: if i do as you said, my header items itself are not expanding.

Comment: if you don't need to any event on group click listener then return false,
If you need to set groupOnClick Listener then you need to manually expand or collapse the group.